# Azure ARM template depend on resources in copy loop

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I am creating ARM template which takes in hash table of subnets and creates those. However, it looks that I need to wait for the first subnet to be ready before creating the second etc. But I do not know how I could depend on the previous subnet in copy loop. My template resource looks like this currently:

```
      {
    "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
    "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets",
    "name": "[concat(parameters('vnetName') , '/' , parameters('subnets').settings[copyIndex()].name)]",
    "location": "[variables('location')]",
    "copy": {
      "name": "subnetLoop",
      "count": "[variables('subnetcount')]"
    },
    "dependsOn": ["[parameters('vnetName')]",
    "[resourceId(variables('rgname'), 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', parameters('vNetName'), parameters('subnets').settings[copyIndex()].name)]"
  ],
    "properties": {
      "addressPrefix": "[parameters('subnets').settings[copyIndex()].addressPrefix]",
       }
```

Which does not work because the first subnet cannot reference itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use `"mode": "serial"` to workaround that.

```
"copy": {
  "name": "subnetLoop",
  "count": "[variables('subnetcount')]",
  "mode": "serial"
},
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-multiple#resource-iteration

but you really need to look at properties loop, check this link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/building-blocks/extending-templates/objects-as-parameters#using-a-property-object-in-a-copy-loop

Comment: What difference does the property loop in this case?

Comment: cleaner, you dont need to deploy subnets as separate resources, you can just deploy vnet with all the subnets, its a lot faster

Comment: ach, I tried that first but the error message pointed me to do it this way.

Comment: just create a new question if you need help with properties loop ;)